# How to find out the contents of a git push

Tags: git

I was wandering if there is a way to see what exactly was included in a given push. I am looking for things like commits and also the push metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, You can use hooks to find out the content of the commit content with git hooks. You can use the `pre-receive` or `post-receive` hooks

### ***[`pre-receive`/`post-receive`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#pre-receive-KpTEIPiaik)***

```bash
#!/bin/sh


# assuming this is not teh first commit. it it is you will have to add extra lines of code
# Check to see if we have updated the given file

# the content can be grabbed using this command: 
if [ $(git diff-tree -r --name-only HEAD^1)  ];

    # Output colors
    red='\033[0;31m';
    green='\033[0;32m';
    yellow='\033[0;33m';
    default='\033[0;m';

    # personal touch :-)
    echo "${red}"
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "                   |                     "
    echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
    echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
    echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
    echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
    echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
    echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
    echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
    echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
    echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
    echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
    echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "                                         "
    echo "      ${green}You have just committed code  " 
    echo "                                         "
    echo "${default}"
```